# Εrror when locking a local variable: "Possibly incorrect assignment to local which is the argument to a using or lock statement."

Tags: c#, multithreading, locking, using-statement

I have an in memory static repository which is used both for writing into it  and reading from it. When writing (updating) that repository, I would like to make it completely exclusively available for update, without letting reading from it (or even let other process updating it). I'm doing so by using the lock mechanism. In the code below - the **UpdateRepoWithItemsBBB**  is updating the repository with the new Items.
I'm trying to figure out 2 things:

1. Is the mechanism work as it should ?
2. What is the reason for the warning message detailed below ?
   This is my code:

   internal async Task UpdateRepo()
   {
   IEnumerable  itemsAAA = await getItemsFRomApi();

   ```
    IEnumerable<ClassBBB> itemsBBB = new List<ClassBBB>();

    lock(itemsBBB)
    {
        itemsBBB = getUpdatedItems(itemsAAA);
        UpdateRepoWithItemsBBB(itemsBBB)
    }
   ```

   }

The local variable `itemsBBB`  has a green wavy line beneath it with a warning\notification:

> Possibly incorrect assignment to local 'itemsBBB' which is the argument to a using or lock statement. The dispose call or unlocking will happen on the original value of the local.

Comment: It's better to describe what you are trying to achieve, because in provided code lock looks completely useless and it's hard to suggest a fix without knowing the goal.

Comment: So, Thread A calls `UpdateRepo`. It creates a new `List<ClassBBB>` object and assigns it to this call's `itemsBBB` variable, and then locks on it. Thread B does exactly the same, creating a new `List<ClassBBB>` and assigning it to *its* `itemsBBB` variable. You have two list objects that know nothing about each other, up to and including whether or not either of them is locked.

Comment: As written, the lock does absolutely nothing, since you lock on the new instance every time (you lock on local variable which you initialize to `new List<...>`). The warning is not related to that. Warning says that you reassign variable you lock on (`itemsBBB`) inside the lock statement itself. So "unlock" will happen on old instance, not the reassigned one.